# c++ polymorphism: upcasting/re-downcasting and containers of base class, missing data

Tags: c++, polymorphism, downcast

I'm trying to fill a vector with derived classes of animals (Dog, Cat, etc). When I take out the contents of the vector, I want to downcast them back to the derived classes.

After doing dog.setLegs(4), I am getting back the correct number of legs with getLegs(). However, after getting back the Animal object from the animals vector and casting that back to type Dog, mydog->getLegs() returns me 0 instead of 4 as I would have expected.

I think I am doing something wrong here but I am not sure what. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!!

```
class Animal{
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
  void setLegs(int newLegs){legs = newLegs;};
  int getLegs(){return legs;};
protected:
  int legs=0;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  Dog dog;
  dog.setLegs(4);
  std::cout<<dog.getLegs()<<std::endl;

  std::vector<Animal> animals;
  animals.push_back(dog);

  Dog *mydog = (Dog*) &(animals[0]);
  std::cout<<mydog->getLegs()<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why isn't your base class abstract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `std::vector` contains only `Animal`s. Putting a subclass of an `Animal` into the vector "slices" off the subclass, leaving just the `Animal` in the vector. The subclass is gone. It's no more.

What you want to do is store pointers to `Animal`'s instead:

```
 std::vector<Animal *> animals;
```

So the relevant chunk of your code becomes:

```
 Dog *mydog = (Dog*)animals[0];
 std::cout<<mydog->getLegs()<<std::endl;
```